# azure devops "git pull" gives "Authentication failed" for no apparent reason

Tags: git, macos, devops

I have been pushing and pulling from my local devops git clone by command line for years, but today out of the blue when I try to do "git pull" I get:

Password for 'https://myorg@dev.azure.com':

I have tried using my microsoft password, but it always fails.  Presumably this is because "myorg" doesn't have an account.

Git remote -v gives this:

```
origin  https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/myproj/_git/myproj (fetch)
origin  https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/myproj/_git/myproj (push)
```

I cant remember how I originally authenticated, but I am pretty sure it was not PAT and it was not SSH cert either.

if I open devops and look at the PAT keys, there are none expired.  All are for next year.  So I dont seem to have used PAT, and pat would presumably require that my remotes start with my name, not the org.

Looking in devops at my "SSH public keys" there are done defined, so its not this either.

How on earth have I been authenticated till now, and how might I fix this problem?  Presumably I need to switch to PAT, but this generally only works if you originally cloned the project using PATs.

In the past I have had a lot of problems with SSH keys so try to avoid this.

Im on an apple silicon Mac by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I saw a lot of posts recommending changing the remotes.

I the end I solved it by going to the repository in devops, clicking "clone", and its showed the same remote that I have, i.e.

```
https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/myproj/_git/myproj
```

Under username, it shows my azure first.last

Under Password, it shows a generated password.

Surprisingly, when I enter this generated password, I can now pull.

So it doesn't seem to be using PAT or SSH, and somewhere it knows my username is "first.last" not "myorg".

[image]